# Use Cell Value to Find Cell within another Workbook and Copy Paste Data

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to enable the updating of another workbook from my current workbook. What I want to do is take a data set and update the specific row of data within another workbook, from which I took the RowID (from the table I have within it)

This code shows what I have so far, but when runs, it doesnt find the value to put into the search field and then nothing is updated.

How can I use a specific cell value (LkupRange) and use this in a Cells.Find to then copy paste a row of data to update?

```
Sub UpdateInvoice()
Dim LkupRange As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
LkupRange = Sheets("CustomerInvoice").Range("P4").Value
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Sheets("CustomerInvoice").Select
Range("P4").Select
Selection.Copy
ChDir "Y:\INVOICES"
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "Y:\SALES INVOICES\SALES INVOICE REGISTER.xlsx"
Range("C3").Select
Debug.Print LkupRange
Cells.Find(What:=LkupRange, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("A1").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWindow.Close
Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: seems like this could be done with VLOOKUP, INDEX and/or MATCH functions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code many times and it worked. Make sure your source sheet matches the destination if you are going to use find.